# How to connect to SQL Server database in Godaddy from a winform application using connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server

Have a Winforms application and want to connect to a SQL Server database in godaddy using connection string.

I am getting the following error - please help.

```
connString = @"Data Source=IP\SERVER2014;Initial Catalog= ;User ID= ;Password= ";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

Getting same error when open from SQL Server Management Studio (local computer)

Error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Are you sure your Mssql server opening or your connection string is correct?

Comment: Actually, the error message says you cannot connect to the SQL server and SSMS says the same. Did you make sure the server's sql server port (default is 1433) is open to you? Can you try to connect to remote server's 1433 port? Or did GoDaddy give you another port to connect?

Comment: The server is on your local computer and you use the IP for the Datasource? Try to use Computername/Sql-Servername. Make sure the sql-service is running (check it under services)

Comment: @Olli - The serve is in Godaddy. Want to open from local computer or application

Comment: @ Abdullah Nehir - please tell me how to check - connect to remote server's 1433 port? I have access to server through Remote Desktop

Comment: @ D-Shih - I am able to open database from server using sql management studio. But not opening from my local computer sql management studio

Comment: You can use telnet to check if you have access to target computer's 1433 port. I can think of two problems here: 1) ip address you're given might be a local ip, so you cannot access from outside of GoDaddy network. If this is the case you should ask help from GoDaddy experts. 2) your firewall might block you if you or your company have any, then you should allow the target port in your firewall.

Comment: or 3) (subtly different from 1 in Abdullah's comment above) GoDaddy's firewall blocks access to SQL Server ports from outside GoDaddy's network. It's possible you might be able to enable it I guess, but generally opening a database port to the public internet is considered a security risk. Maybe they have a way for you to specify particular client machines which would be allowed to access it remotely. I don't know the specifics of the hosting company or environment, you'd have to ask their help team or forums

Comment: or possibly even 4) The SQL Server is configured not to accept connections from _any_ remote machine, even within the GoDaddy network. Again, you can talk to their support personnel about what the setup is, and whether it's possible to re-configure it to suit your needs.

Comment: A more conventional architecture in this sort of scenario however would be to either a) ditch the WinForms app in favour of a web-based application which is also hosted in the GoDaddy server, and can therefore access the database with no problem, or b) create a Web-based API (again hosted on the GoDaddy server) which acts as an intermediary between the WinForms app and the database. The WinForms app would make HTTP requests to the API, which would then contact the database, process the result and return it to the application in the response to the HTTP request

Comment: Option b) has other potential advantages, in that if the bulk of the database and data processing logic, plus authentication mechanisms etc are hosted in the API, then you can easily add other types of client application to your eco-system, e.g. mobile apps, web-based UIs, services, command-line apps which can all make use of the API to provide them with the same functionality, without re-writing anything except the UI logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection string was the problem.

Data Source=IP\SERVER2014 instead used Data Source=IP.

connString = @"Data Source=IP;Initial Catalog= ;User ID= ;Password= ";

Thanks.